# Twitter bootstrap 2.3.1 popover doesn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I don't know what to do I have spend about 40 minutes for adding popover to image and without results, I have working popover on another project, I copied all from that project, but still doesn't working :( On older project I use 2.3.0 boostrap on this newer I use 2.3.1 and can't add popover :@ there is my code:

```
<img id="img" src="http://has.lv/uploads/profile/photo-178.jpg" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Test" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Title" />

<script type="test/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#img').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
});
</script>
```

and the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Enw68/

and yes I have added jquery and boostrap js files!

Comment: You're missing tooltip.js, a prerequisite for popover.js.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing tooltip.js, a prerequisite for popover.js.

http://jsfiddle.net/Enw68/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#img').popover({
        trigger: "hover"
    });
});
```

Comment: I downloaded bootstrap zip file witch includes 2 css files and 2 js files, all other js plugins work, only popover doesnt :@

Comment: Thanks, lurii.K. I'd have sworn my original fiddle was more complete. Answer updated for posterity.